# WCF RIA - One to Many, returning only first row

Tags: c#, wcf, devexpress, ria

Hi I have the following relationships:

```
return this.ObjectContext.PCRs.Include("PApproval").Include("Details").Include("PApproval.PStatus");
```

"PApproval" table contains more then one row, however is it possible to only get the first record from that table based on the latest date(column Last Updated on). Reason for this is so I can bind to my DXGrid, being able to show the latest approval status

Answer (score 0):

You can try to order the results so the newest record will be first, then only select the first record.

```
return this.ObjectContext.PCRs.Include("PApproval").Include("Details").Include("PApproval.PStatus").OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdatedOn).First();
```